# Apache Mod Rewrite Conf to ignore part of URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2, apache-config

Let's say I have the domain `http://www.example.com`.

When I browse to `http://www.example.com/12345` it brings me the person having id 12345 from database.  I want it to work even I write some other meaningless bunch of characters at the end of the URL; `http://www.example.com/12345/qwerty`.

This is the current config:

```
RewriteRule ^/(\d+)$ /person.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What should I add to this config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RewriteRule ^/(\d+) /person.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]`

ignores everthing after the numbers..